# Generating a code failed on afterr_save call back on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to adding a unique value in a table column when the record is saved.

Assume my table have 3 fields : < Job_Code >

In my POST request I send the following payload :
{ "customer_id":"123", "customer_name":"Jay"}

If this record is saved to the database. Then I need to update the `Job_Code` column in using generated code like `JOB_123_458` where 458 is the unique id for the record.

I am tying to using the `after_save` callback on Active Class and update the new value on it.

I am using the following way :

```
after_save :update_job_code

def update_job_code
   update_column(:job_code, "JOB_" + :customer_id + "_" + :id)
end
```

But I could not able to generate a Job code in the format of `JOB_<Customer_id>_<Newly Created Job Id>`

Let me know how do i generate the job code in relevant format in Active Record `after_save` call back

Comment: What is the issue ? How do you access `params[:customer_id]` in model ?

Comment: Huh, "let me know"? I don't think this is the way to ask for help. But that IMO.

Comment: In Model I need to generate a job code in the format I have metioned on the above question. So my idea is after saving the object . Then getting the id and update to the particular record. for this I have concate the values `"JOB_"` with `:customer_id`  the values are not concatinating

Comment: Please check my question I have updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:customer_id` and `:id` are just symbols.  What you want is to call the attributes of the record so just remove the colons.

It is also better to use [string interpolation](http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/bonus/string_interpolation.html) so instead of creating multiple strings, you just create a single string.

```
def update_job_code
  update_column(:job_code, "JOB_#{customer_id}_#{id}")
end
```

Comment: Are we able to check the validation_of_uniqueness while crating the update_column methods

Comment: ah no. `update_column` only fires an sql, no validations and callbacks are called.  since `job_code` is just a combination of `customer_id` and `id`, just run the uniqueness validation against those 2 columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
after_save :update_job_code

def update_job_code
   p customer_id.inpsect # to see customer id in log for debug
   update_column(:job_code, "JOB_" + customer_id + "_" + id) unless job_code.present?
end
```

Just remove `:` it's for symbols definitions, you want to actually call attributes.